# Images and Linear Transformations

Tags: image-processing, geometric-transform

I was playing around with some of the Image processing commands like [*ImageRotate*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageRotate.html).

I thought it would be fun to try and make up some basic linear transformation rules - starting in 2D and then going to [*3D*](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_graphics/3d_transformation.htm).

I wrote up some naive rules as:

```
iden = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}; (* identity, leave all points unmoved *)

axisres[a_, b_] := {{a, 0}, {0, b}} (* axis rescaling *)

rot[th_] := {{Cos[th],-Sin[th]},{Sin[th],Cos[th]}} (* rotation *)

reflect = {{-1, 0}, {0, 1}}; (* reflection *)

shearleft[a_] := {{1, a}, {0, 1}} (* shear left direction *)

shearright[b_] := {{1, 0}, {b, 1}} (* shear right direction *)
```

However, when I do the following - only the identity works properly.

```
 image1 = {{0.1, 0.2}, {0.4, 0.5}};

 Image[image1]

 Image[image1.iden]

 Image[image1.axisres[1,2]]

 Image[image1.rot[Pi]]

 Image[image1.reflect]

 Image[image1.shearleft[.2]]

 Image[image1.shearright[-.2]]
```

I suspect it is some silly error, but I still do not see it. Why do these simple transformations not preserve the image and just perform their intended operation?

Comment: Those transformations are designed to work on the position of a pixel, that is its coordinates.  Whereas the image data you are applying them to, is just an array of pixel intensities.

Comment: So, I have to somehow use an image as opposed to the way I defined the image? Maybe easier, how can I get the transformations to do what I need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want here is `ImageForwardTransformation[]`. For instance, to demonstrate rotation and shearing, we can do this:

```
lenna = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];

(* rotation *)
ImageForwardTransformation[lenna, RotationTransform[π/4], DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image: Lenna rotated by 45°]

```
(* shearing + translation *)
ImageForwardTransformation[lenna, AffineTransform[{{{1, Sqrt[3]/2}, {0, 1}}, {1/2, 0}}], 
                           DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image: sheared Lenna]

Note the use of a `TransformationFunction[]` (`RotationTransform[]` in the first case, and the more general `AffineTransform[]` in the second case) to perform the mapping, as well as the use of the `DataRange` option to specify the domain in which the image being transformed is embedded in.

Comment: I can certainly use the built in functions, but is there a way to get the naive variants that I posted to work?

Comment: As wxffles explained in a comment, performing affine transformations on an image is different from applying that same affine transformation to the array of graylevel/RGB intensities that make up an image. You certainly could try re-implementing `ImageForwardTransformation[]`, but I'm not sure why you want to.

Comment: Okay, I understand - thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Just for completeness sake: You *can* use your own transformation functions, with `ImageTransformation` or `ImageForwardTransformation`, like this:

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Clock"}];
ImageTransformation[img, rot[π/4].# &, DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]

ImageTransformation[img, reflect.# &, DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

The second argument to `ImageTransformation` is a function that gets an xy coordinate pair in the destination image and returns a transformed xy coordinate pair in the source image.